# How to restore Telegram ANGLE graphics backend to Auto using arguments?

Tags: telegram-messenger

I know how to do it using GUI, but as I have changed it to Direct3D (one of its variants), after restart, it won't run and I need to change it using arguments like:
"c:\telegram.exe -ANGLEAuto"